# Bootstrap paragraph aligned in different columns

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a wordpress page and using the following code:

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
    <?php
     if(have_posts()):
        while(have_posts()):
            the_post();
            echo '<div class="col-sm-3 border">';
            the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>');  //echo <h3>The Title</h3>
            the_excerpt();
            echo '</div>';
        endwhile;
        endif;
     ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The blogroll is displaying like this:

[Bootstrap align the rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eNUN.jpg)

And i want to display something like this: (sorry for paint)

[no aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iR69.jpg)

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that great with PHP, but I think you can do something with a Modulus to make a new row.

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
<div class='row'>
<?php

if(have_posts()):

    counter = 1;
    while(have_posts()):

        if (counter % 4 == 0) {
            echo '</div><div class="row">';
        }
        the_post();
        echo '<div class="col-sm-3 border">';
        the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>');  //echo <h3>The Title</h3>
        the_excerpt();
        echo '</div>';
        counter++;
    endwhile;
endif;
 ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer... I will try as soon as i will can

Comment: I hope it helps.  You will probably need to move the_post() inside of your col-sm-3

Comment: Hi....yes....but its almost the same....if I have a larger div.... the other 4 divs on the next row will come in a line.... i find something that approach my problem.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height?rq=1  but its not exactly what i want

Comment: After some time i found the solution....there's a framework named masonJs...which is used for exact this... good to know for you or maybe for anyone who read this.